# I'm having trouble printing the correct content

Tags: javascript, html, background-color, styling

I have given the background color of the print window to be white but like all the other windows, this too is coming as grey.. What change should I implement?

```
function printDiv(divName) {
    var originalStore = document.getElementById('storeid').value;


    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
    document.getElementById('storeid').value = originalStore;


    window.print();
    //    $('#print').printElement();
    document.bgColor = "#ffffff"
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
    document.getElementById('storeid').value = originalStore;

}​
```

Comment: Not even typing the following in the global css is helping matters: @media print{  body{background-color:#ffffff;} }

Answer (score 0):

> I have given the background color of the print window to be white but
>   like all the other windows, this too is coming as grey.. What change
>   should I implement?

It is `backgroundColor` not `bgColor`:

```
document.backgroundColor="#ffffff"
```

Comment: Not helping.. It's still grey.. It's changing only if I change the global body background to white